# Regular expressions - Creating a list by words extraction from text

Tags: python

Example:

```
myList = []
text = ["salmonella in black pepper from brazil", "aflatoxins in fish from germany", "pseudomonas in meat from italy"]
findmatches = re.compile(r"\b" +
                         r"\b|\b".join(re.escape(hazard) for hazard in hazards_set) +
                         r"\b")

for i in text:
    for possible_match in set(findmatches.findall(i)):
        if possible_match in hazards_set:
            myList.append(possible_match)
    myList.append("")

print(myList)
```

This is what I get:
`['salmonella', '', 'aflatoxins', '', '']`

This is what I would like to get:
`['salmonella','aflatoxins', '']`
since "pseudomonas" is not in the set hazards_set.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: what is `hazards_set`?

Comment: Create your [mcve] and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an `if` condition for the first `for-loop` using [`.isdisjoint()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/isdisjoint.html) to append the appropriate empty string.

```py
myList = []
text = ["salmonella in black pepper from brazil", "aflatoxins in fish from germany", "pseudomonas in meat from italy"]
findmatches = re.compile(r"\b" +
                         r"\b|\b".join(re.escape(hazard) for hazard in hazards_set) +
                         r"\b")
# e.g
hazards_set = ['brrrrrrrr', 'aflatoxins', 'salmonella']
for i in text:
    for possible_match in set(findmatches.findall(i)):
        if possible_match in hazards_set:
            myList.append(possible_match)
    if set(findmatches.findall(i)).isdisjoint(hazards_set): 
        myList.append("")

print(myList)
```

---

```
['salmonella', 'aflatoxins', '']
```

You can also choose to improve the code using [list-comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html) and [`re.finditer()`](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/book/15_module_re/finditer.html) with a different re pattern

```py
myList = [match.group(0) for i in text 
          for match in re.finditer(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(hazards_set), i)]
myList +=[''] * (len(text) - len(myList))
print(myList)
```

Will produce the same output as the traditional for-loop and append approach.
**Note:** I am anticipating that `hazards_set` could either be a list of words like:

```py
hazards_set = ['brrrrrrrr', 'aflatoxins', 'salmonella']
```

or set of words like:

```py
hazards_set = {'brrrrrrrr', 'aflatoxins', 'salmonella'}
```

Comment: Now the code works correctly, thanks!